# Can we make custom polygon shaped collection view items inside collection view

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, custom-cell

[image]

I want to achieve something like this. I know that this is very simple if i keep a set of images and just keep switching between them to update the status, but i want to do this using collection view.

Comment: I don't understand the need of `UICollectionView`. Anyway, if I had to implement this with a collection view, I would create my own class for the cells that have this shape. A better touch tracking can be done by overwriting `point(inside:with:)`. Positioning can be achieved via a separate collection view layout.

Comment: Thanks @macmoonshine, i actually achieved the same using custom cell. Its just that i dint want to miss out on some other option available, so asked the question.